# Installing distutils dependency for python3 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: package-management, dependencies, python3, pip

I tried to install distutils and here's what i got this problem:

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>
> python3-distutils : Depends: python3 (>= 3.6.8-1~) but 3.6.7-1~18.04
>   is to be installed
>
> E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

I updated everything there is to be updated on my Ubuntu 18.04.
I have python3.7 and python3.6.9 (currently selected) installed.
there are no held packages.
using aptitude command gives me the same results and suggests:

> The following actions will resolve these dependencies:
>
> ```
> Keep the following packages at their current version:
> ```
>
> 1)     python3-distutils [Not Installed]
>
> 2)     python3-lib2to3 [Not Installed]

which doesn't install, update or remove anything and leaves me in the same place.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Comment: Go to this question's revision history to see the complete error messages which are only excerpted here.